# Local minima and derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization

I would want to follow the proof of the statement:

> If a twice differentiable function $f: S\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ being an open set has a local minima at point $x^*$ then $f'(x^*) =0 $.

The author proofs this by *contraposition* ($f'(x*) \neq 0 $) in the following way:

$f(x^*+h) = f(x^*) + f'(x^*)h + o(h)$ using small o-notation

In the next step he defines $\eta := \frac{1}{2}|f'(x^*)| $ and states
$ \exists  \delta >0: \forall h \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|h| <\delta$ such that $\frac{f(x^*+h) -f(x^*) - f'(x^*)h }{h} < \eta $

Could someone provide an intuition on how $\eta$ is derived and why such a  $\delta$ is needed ?

Comment: $\eta$ just has to be a number which is positive, and less than $|f’(x^*)|$ (which is itself a positive number since we’re assuming in contraposition that $f’(x^*)\neq 0$). Why this choice? because it makes things work out with the signs. $\eta$ just has to be a number which is positive, and less than $|f’(x^*)|$ (which is itself a positive number since we’re assuming in contraposition that $f’(x^*)\neq 0$). Why this choice? Because it makes things work out with the signs. The exact choice of constant $\frac{1}{2}$ is unimportant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

transfer everything except for o(h) on the LHS, use the definition of o(h) - particularly the definition of a limit (epsilon delta definition), put epsilon := (1/2)|f′(x∗)|. Normal people use epsilon instead of η imo it makes thing more clean

$f(x^*+h)-f(x^*)-f'(x^*)h=o(h)\implies \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x^*+h)-f(x^*)-f'(x^*)h}{h}=0 \implies \forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall h:(h<\delta \implies \frac{f(x^*+h)-f(x^*)-f'(x^*)h}{h} < \epsilon)$

Put $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}|f(x^*)|>0$ because $f(x^*)\not=0$